# Command for separating/distinguising tcpstreams in pcap file on Linux

Tags: linux, wireshark, tcpdump, rhel, tshark

I have a huge pcap file in which there thousand of tcpstreams , i need to separate these tcpstream and find out out packet loss for each of them , i am trying out TSHARK(http://www.faultserver.com/q/answers-how-to-calculate-packet-loss-from-a-binary-tcpdump-file-336588.html) , which can help me find out packet loss , retransmission but it dose that for entire pcap file . I want to get it for separate tcpstreams on my Linux box .

Thanks in advance.
Jain

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked out for me with the following tshark commands :

## tshark -r trace_2013-11-22_16:03:22.pcap -q -z ip_hosts,tree

Running as user "root" and group "root". This could be dangerous.

===================================================================

### IP Addresses            value          rate         percent

IP Addresses           11974       0.003422
  27.61.14.188           9729       0.002781          81.25%
  192.168.44.44          11974       0.003422         100.00%
  101.223.166.12          311       0.000089           2.60%
  223.178.146.17          325       0.000093           2.71%
  223.228.148.15          465       0.000133           3.88%
  223.182.31.6            313       0.000089           2.61%
  117.96.87.7             711       0.000203           5.94%
  171.78.138.26            120       0.000034           1.00%

===================================================================

tshark -r trace_2013-11-22_16:03:22.pcap  -q io,stat,12000,"ip.addr==27.61.14.188 #&& tcp","COUNT(tcp.analysis.retransmission)ip.addr==27.61.14.188 && tcp.analysis.retransmission","COUNT(tcp.analysis.duplicate_ack)ip.addr==27.61.14.188 && tcp.analysis.duplicate_ack","COUNT(tcp.analysis.lost_segment)ip.addr==27.61.14.188 &&  tcp.analysis.lost_segment","COUNT(tcp.analysis.fast_retransmission)ip.addr==27.61.14.188 && tcp.analysis.fast_retransmission"

Running as user "root" and group "root". This could be dangerous.

===================================================================
IO Statistics
Interval: 12000.000 secs
Column #0: ip.addr==27.61.14.188 && tcp
Column #1: COUNT(tcp.analysis.retransmission)ip.addr==27.61.14.188 && tcp.analysis.retransmission
Column #2: COUNT(tcp.analysis.duplicate_ack)ip.addr==27.61.14.188 && tcp.analysis.duplicate_ack
Column #3: COUNT(tcp.analysis.lost_segment)ip.addr==27.61.14.188 &&  tcp.analysis.lost_segment
Column #4: COUNT(tcp.analysis.fast_retransmission)ip.addr==27.61.14.188 && tcp.analysis.fast_retransmission
                |   Column #0    |   Column #1    |   Column #2    |   Column #3    |   Column #4
Time            |frames|  bytes  |          COUNT |          COUNT |          COUNT |          COUNT

## 000.000-12000.000    9729   7519861              393             1900                1              283

Thanks,
Jain